# SQLite (select): I don't get it

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I don't get the solution for my needs:

My code:

```
select vocbox._id, vocbox.name, vocbox.native, vocbox.foreign, count(_id_vocbox) as count
from vocbox
left join vocable on vocable._id_vocbox=vocbox._id
group by vocbox._id;
```

...only delivers this:

[image]

but, what i want is this:

[image]

and this are my tables:

[image]

I hope somebody knows the right code..

Comment: JOIN with Language twice

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: i don't understand, why somebody marked my Question as negative..  cause i did my best to visual my problem.. (it cost me time to make the illustrations) and now with the answer from sebastien sevrin i understand everything :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query

```
select vocbox._id, vocbox.name, ln.name as native, lf.name as foreign, count(_id_vocbox) as count
from vocbox
left join vocable on vocable._id_vocbox=vocbox._id
left join language as ln on ln._id = vocbox.native
left join language as lf on lf._id = vocbox.foreign
group by vocbox._id;
```

Comment: Sebastien Sevrin - thank you very much!! :)
it works :) and now i have understand it.
and with this trick now, i solved the other problems too. :)
(sry, my english is not so good)